# Creating a Stepper using React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I am trying to create a Stepper using react and redux. The concept I am using for it is -

1. Store the active step in redux store.
2. I have a list of components and each component is associated with an index.
3. In parent component, I render the component whose index is equal to active step.

Here's the code for parent component -

I have component step map -

```
const COMPONENT_STEP_MAP = {
    1: (props) => (
        <Component1
        {...props}
        render = {(props) => <Buttons {...props}/>}
        ></Component1>
    ),
    2: (props) => (
        <Component2
        {...props}
        render = {(props) => <Buttons {...props}/>}
        ></Component2>
    ),}
```

Here's How my Redux Store looks like -

```
const initialState = {
  activeTab: 1,
  basicDetails: {
    activeStep: 1,
    name: '',
    }
```

Here's the render function of the parent component -

```
 export class ParentComponent extends React.component {
        handleNext = () => {
          if(this.props.activeStep == 1 && 
         this.props.isBusinessOwner==false){ // isBusinessOwner is not showing correct value.
            this.props.setActiveStep(this.props.activeStep + 2)
          }
          else this.props.setActiveStep(this.props.activeStep + 1);
        };
          handlePrevious = () => {
            if(this.props.activeStep == 1 && 
             this.props.isBusinessOwner==false){
              this.props.setActiveStep(this.props.activeStep - 2);
            } else
            this.props.setActiveStep(this.props.activeStep - 1)
          };

       render() {
        return ({Object.entries(COMPONENT_STEP_MAP).map((comp) => {
                      return comp[0] == this.props.activeStep
                        ? comp[1]({handlePrevious, handleNext}):null}}) } }
```

I am using react-redux to connect it to the store -

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({activeStep: state.ownerDetails.activeStep, isBusinessOwner: state.ownerDetails.isBusinessOwner});
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    setActiveStep: (step) => dispatch({type: 'ownerDetails', payload:{activeStep: step}})
  })

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OwnerDetails);
```

Now I have following child component

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

export function IsOwner(props) {
    const isOwner = useSelector(state => state.ownerDetails.isBusinessOwner);
    const setIsBusinessOwner = useDispatch();
    const handleChange = (value) => {
        // console.log('value', value);
        setIsBusinessOwner({type: 'ownerDetails', payload: {isBusinessOwner: value}})
        props.handleNext();
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Are You Business Owner</h4>
            <button onClick={handleChange.bind(null,true)}>Yes</button>
            <button onClick={handleChange.bind(null,false)}>No</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have doubt in following 2 lines -

```
setIsBusinessOwner({type: 'ownerDetails', payload: {isBusinessOwner: value}})
props.handleNext();
```

`setIsBusinessOwner` updates the store and will force the component to re-render. 
**However, I am immediately calling `props.handleNext()` after it , and component will be gone from the DOM.**

**So, When I access `isBusinessOwner` from store in parent component. It is reflecting the previous value not the updated value.**

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Why don't you use REDUX-FORM here is the link -> https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/wizard/ ->this has code for stepper form and it has all the type of examples you need and they are every simple and handle most of your task and code is readily available there  you may have to do  some minor changes thats it

Comment: Thanks!. but how do I skip a step based on a condition ?